# How to update state in React at onClick rather than the next click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to train myself with React and their default tic tac toe tutorial (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) had these challenges

1. DONE : Display the location for each move in the format (col, row) in the
   move history list.
2. DONE : Bold the currently selected item in the move list.
3. DONE : Rewrite Board to use two loops to make the squares instead of hardcoding them.
4. DONE : Add a toggle button that lets you sort the moves in either ascending or descending order.
5. PENDING : When someone wins, highlight the three squares that caused the win.
6. PENDING : When no one wins, display a message about the result being a draw.

   I am stuck with the last 2

**When someone wins, highlight the three squares that caused the win.**

I am able to highlight the last winners based on this code where I am picking up the `winner` prop from the state's `winningLine` Array property.

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.active || props.winner ? (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
          <strong>{props.value}</strong>
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span>{props.value}</span>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

But the problem is it doesn't happen on click.. rather it happens on the next click. I've done my research and it seems this normal and there's a lag or delay and it's how react works. Is this true? I am sure there's a way to do highlight the winning rows but I am not able to figure it out and I've struggled a few hours and heading nowhere. Could someone please help?

**When no one wins, display a message about the result being a draw.**

Even for this, I think the issue is that I am not able to get the state on the last click and so I am not sure how to do this. Here's my attempt at the code which does not work.

```
    // IF IT'S A TIE
    if (this.state.stepNumber === 9 && this.state.winningLine.length === 0) {
      alert("It is a tie!!!");
    }
```

Here's the index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";

function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.active || props.winner ? (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
          <strong>{props.value}</strong>
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span>{props.value}</span>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        key={i}
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
        active={this.props.currentCell === i}
        winner={this.props.winningCells.includes(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBoard = () => {
    let squareRows = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      const squareCols = [];
      for (let y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        squareCols.push(this.renderSquare(count));
        count++;
      }
      squareRows.push(squareCols);
      console.log("squareRows", squareRows);
    }
    return squareRows;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderBoard().map((squareRow, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="board-row">
              {squareRow.map((square) => square)}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [{ squares: Array(9).fill(null) }],
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true,
      selectedCells: [null],
      currentCell: null,
      sort: true,
      winningLine: [],
    };
  }

  calculateWinner = (squares) => {
    const lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
      console.log("a", squares[a], "b", squares[b], "c", squares[c]);
      if (
        squares[a] &&
        squares[a] === squares[b] &&
        squares[a] === squares[c]
      ) {
        // return squares[a];
        return { winningSquare: squares[a], winningLine: lines[i] };
      }
    }
    return null;
  };

  handleClick = async (i) => {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    const cells = this.state.selectedCells.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);

    console.log("current", current);
    console.log("squares", squares);

    // const { winningLine } = this.calculateWinner(squares);

    if (squares[i]) {
      console.log("exists", squares[i]);
      return;
    }

    let winner = this.calculateWinner(squares);
    if (this.calculateWinner(squares)) {
      this.setState(() => ({ winningLine: winner.winningLine }));
      return;
    }

    // IF IT'S A TIE
    if (this.state.stepNumber === 9 && this.state.winningLine.length === 0) {
      alert("It is a tie!!!");
    }

    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    console.log(squares);

    this.setState(() => ({
      history: history.concat([{ squares: squares }]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
      selectedCells: cells.concat([i]),
      currentCell: i,
    }));
  };

  jumpTo = (step) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ stepNumber: step, xIsNext: step % 2 === 0 }));
  };

  sortMoves = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({ sort: !this.state.sort }));
  };

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = this.calculateWinner(current.squares);
    const cells = this.state.selectedCells;

    const moves = history
      .map((step, move) => {
        console.log("move", move);
        console.log(cells[move]);

        const col = (cells[move] % 3) + 1;
        const row = Math.ceil((cells[move] + 1) / 3);
        const desc = move
          ? "Col:" + col + "Row" + row + "Go to move #" + move
          : "Go to start";

        return (
          <li key={move} data-order={move}>
            <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
          </li>
        );
      })
      .sort();
    let status;

    if (winner?.winningSquare) {
      status = "Winner" + winner.winningSquare;
    } else {
      status = "Next Player" + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
    }

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
            currentCell={this.state.currentCell}
            winningCells={this.state.winningLine}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{this.state.sort ? moves : moves.reverse()}</ol>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.sortMoves()}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Game />);
```

and here's the index.css

```
body {
  font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.kbd-navigation .square:focus {
  background: #ddd;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

and here's link to the codesandbox.io

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tutorial-tic-tac-toe-9xygu4?file=/src/index.js

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Keith, who helped me resolve the issue with some magic suggestions..:-).. I am now trying to resolve the second part and this code works fine when I am on `this.state.stepNumber` 8 which is just before the last step but I'd want it to happen after the last step which is 9.. any suggestions?

```
    // IF IT'S A TIE
    if (this.state.stepNumber === 9 && this.state.winningLine.length === 0) {
      alert("It is a tie!!!");
    }
```

Comment: Your calling `this.calculateWinner`  before you have even set the square -> `squares[i] = `  So this is not actually anything to do with React rendering lifecycle.

Comment: @Keith thanks for the response. I see what you are saying and it seems correct, what you are saying. Could you suggest how I could change the sequence? coz I know that there's a render function which has a return option for the markup and the only place where  I could call the `this.calculateWinner' was where I have done it.. could you please advise how else and from where else I can call it?

Comment: Jus place your `squares[i] = ` before calling `this.calculateWinner`,  also take out the `return` so that the `setState` still gets called, otherwise there will be no re-render of the new state.  eg. -> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tutorial-tic-tac-toe-forked-vgkezv?file=/src/index.js:2789-2808

Comment: @Keith thanks.. that worked!!.. the `return` I have removed and it re-renders but now even after the `winner` exists the game still goes on.. but I'll figure a way out for that.. it's a relief getting out of the maze i was in.. :-).. i'll get back to it and bother you if I have any further queries, which I hope i will not have..:-)... thanks again..

Comment: Just do a winner check at the begging,  and then return this time..    https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tutorial-tic-tac-toe-forked-vgkezv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: perfect!!..:-).. will focus on the last task now.. how to alert when it's a tie..

Comment: @Keith : have added an UPDATE at the end of my question.. could you please suggest how to resolve that part?

Comment: Just use `history.length`, as this is what you end up putting into `stepNumber` anyway..  ->  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tutorial-tic-tac-toe-forked-vgkezv?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score -1):

The problem is React render functionality.

You have to render again when this situation happens.

With Hooks, you have to rerender with useEffect(). https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You are using class. You can do the same with componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount. https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html